# Intel Edison: Can't establish Socket Connection with my Laptop

Tags: java, sockets, intel-edison

I'm new to Intel Edison programing. I set up my device and connected it to my local network via wi-fi. I use the following code to create a `ServerSocket`:

```
public class SensorServer {

    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket client;
    int port;

    public SensorServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    private void waitForConnectionAndConnect() throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("***** Server: Wait for connection");

        client = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("***** Server: Connected!");

        while(!client.isConnected())
            ;
        System.out.println("***** Server started successfully!");

    }

    // Helper method for closing the TCP connections
    private void closeConnections() throws IOException {
            client.close();
            serverSocket.close();
    }

    // Helper method to send a message via one of TCP sockets
    private void sendSensorData(SensorData sensorData, ObjectMapper om) throws IOException {
        String json = om.writeValueAsString(sensorData);
        PrintWriter printWriter;
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        printWriter.print(json + "\n");
        printWriter.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SensorServer server = new SensorServer(1234);
            server.waitForConnectionAndConnect();

            System.out.println("Connected!!!");

            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                SensorData sd = server.generateSensorDataRandomly();
                server.sendSensorData(sd, om);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

            server.closeConnections();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private SensorData generateSensorDataRandomly() {
        ...
    }



}
```

This server socket seems to be created successfully, as I don't get any exceptions. When I try to connect to my Edison from my PC, I get an `Connection Refused: Connect` exception. This is the client side code:

```
public class ClientClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
            Socket socket = null; 
            try { 
                socket = new Socket("edison-public-ip", 1234); 

                OutputStream raus = socket.getOutputStream(); 
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(raus, true); 
                ps.println("Hallo Welt!"); 

                InputStream rein = socket.getInputStream(); 
                System.out.println("verfügbare Bytes: " + rein.available()); 
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rein)); 

                while (buff.ready()) { 
                    System.out.println(buff.readLine()); 
                } 

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
                System.out.println("Unknown Host..."); 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                System.out.println("IOProbleme..."); 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } finally { 
                if (socket != null) 
                    try { 
                        socket.close(); 
                        System.out.println("Socket geschlossen..."); 
                    } catch (IOException e) { 
                        System.out.println("Socket nicht zu schliessen..."); 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 
            } 

    }
}
```

And this my exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(ClientClass.java:15)
```

When I try to connect two laptops with each other the code works fine!

**EDIT: Edited the iptables on my board, still without success**

I added the two rules for allowing all incoming and outgoing traffic to my board via `iptables`:

```
iptables -F // Remove all rules
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

But still getting the exception!

Comment: Check the firewall configuration of your Edison, probably firewall is blocking the connection!

Comment: Is there a firewall on the Edison board? And how can I configure it? Can you give my an example or some links?

Comment: It must have, Probably, Linux running in the background! SO, play with the OS and configure the firewall properly. I don't have much idea about how intel-edison works!

Comment: Tried to accept all incoming and outgoing traffic to/from my board, still getting the exception. See the "Edit" in my question.

Comment: While thoroughly going through the code, I saw that you have declared the server as `edison-public-ip`, is it resolvable on client-side? Are you able to successfully ping the name? If not, then add a manual entry to hosts file OR switch to IP address of the server.

Comment: I only set this "name" as I didn't want to write the IP address here... I use the boards IP address 141.xxx.xxx.xxx in the code.

Comment: Are you able to ping the IP-address successfully? If yes, then is your server on edison running? Also, are they on the same network?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121167/discussion-between-d-muller-and-am-i-helpful).